# Can an ordinary point be a fixed point?

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry

Is it possible that a point on the unit circle which is an ordinary point (that is, a point which is **not** a limit point of any set of the form $\Gamma z$ for $|z| <1$) for a Fuchsian group $\Gamma$ (acting on the Poincare hyperbolic disk) is fixed by a nontrivial element of that group? What if it is also a vertex at infinity for a Dirichlet domain for the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first thought the question might be a bit tricky and that one would need to go through the classification of Fuchsian groups (elementary, first kind, second kind...) but actually I think it's pretty straightforward to answer that no, this never happens!

Since elliptics have no fixed points on $\partial \mathbb{D}$, you only need to look at fixed points of parabolic or hyperbolic elements of $\Gamma$. But in both cases, it is easy to see that those are limit points, just using powers of your parabolic/hyperbolic element.

Is that convincing?

Comment: Ah! yes, thank you.